# Spring security ldap/active directory sample

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I could not find a working sample which shows Spring security ldap/active directory  auth. can someone point or share me if anyone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at [Grant Cermak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411327/grant-cermak)'s Active Directory code here.  I have used it and it works great.

http://git.springsource.org/~grantcermak/spring-security/activedirectory-se-security